# issue creating a array using attributes from another class (using typescript)

Tags: arrays, typescript, class, object, attributes

I am trying to create an array of objects from one class in another class but when I push them it throws an error saying "Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Can anybody help me?
Here my example: (I am using typescript)

export class Vector {

```
private elements:Array<number>

constructor(n:number, k:number){
    this.elements = []
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
        this.elements.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*k)+1);
    } 
}
```

}

class Matrix {

```
private elements:Vector[];

constructor(n:number, m:number, k:number) {
   this.elements = new Array();
   for (let i=0; i<n; i++){   
        for (let j=0; j<m; j++) {
            this.elements[i][j].push(Math.floor(Math.random()*k)+1)
        }    
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please fix your code formatting, it's kind of messed up.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `this.elements = new Array` should be `this.elements = new Array()`

And you can't do `this.elements[i][j].push()` because `this.elements[i][j]` doesn't exist, you can't push to `undefined`.

It should go like this:

```
constructor(n:number, m:number, k:number) {
    this.elements = new Array();
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++){
        this.elements.push(new Array());
        for (let j=0; j<m; j++) {
            this.elements[i].push(Math.floor(Math.random()*k)+1)
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working that way . for this.elements.push(new Array()) it is says that argument of type any[] is not assignable to parameter of type Vector